# Using ModelBuilder Delete Tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

[image]

I have a model that generates a list of materials for a proposed project. It has no parameters which is what I want, and it runs almost perfectly. For some reason if I open it to EDIT and run the process it generates my .XLS file perfectly, but if I just run it from Toolbox it'll generate the file and quickly delete it.

Does anyone know why this happens?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the model in a screen shot as well as when you run it from Toolbox?

Comment: @whyzar I've added the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outputs that are set as intermediate are cleared by the model upon completion. I suspect your output is set to intermediate (default) and you need to change this. Simply right click on it and un-tick it.

Why it exists when you run the model from within modelbuilder is that modelbuilder needs to maintain a ready to run status, hence that option is not honoured when a model is run in that way.